# ¿Como mostrar la ruta a seguir en un web service?

Tags: php, javascript, webservice, ionic

he estado trabajando con js y php, me han pedido crear un webservice donde por medio de AJAX pida las coordenadas para mostrarlas en un mapa con el API de Google.

Todo listo pero quisiera saber como crear una ruta a seguir y que este se muestre en el mapa.

Soy un novato la verdad, aquí estoy en cero.

Answer (score 0):

En la misma página de developers de Google te explica un poco por encima como hacer la petición para obtener la ruta que tienes que seguir:
[Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

si no recuerdo mal (ya no tengo acceso a esa aplicación) utilicé algo así:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=[origen]&destination=[destino]&key=[APIKEY]
```

Dónde origen y destino pueden ser nombres de calles(los espacios deben cambiar a +) o coordenadas (latitud, longitud)